# Define regexp pattern as unsigned char

Tags: c++, regex

Is there any way I can create a regex pattern with that contains an unsigned char? I've tried:

```
regex* r = new regex("\\xff");
```

which results in an exception saying the pattern character is out of range. I've also tried to define my own basic_regex and my own regex_traits following the code in the regex include file but that results in a strange error in the local include.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a legal HexEscapeSequence in ECMAScript regex (which is what C++ uses by default), and it appears to work on my tests:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    std::regex re("\\xff");
    std::string test = "abc\xff";

    std::smatch m;
    regex_search(test, m, re);

    std::cout << "Found " << m.size() << " match after '"
              << m.prefix() << "'\n";
}
```

> clang++/libc++: Found 1 match after 'abc'
>
> g++/boost.regex (replacing std:: with boost::): Found 1 match after 'abc'

what's your implementation?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2010. Apparently, it's checking for a valid char type which is < 127.